# Remapping a key to Escape in Vim (German keyboard)

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard, console

Okay, so I've been trying out Vim (the standard console version; my OS is Linux Mint 13) and I'd like to get rid of having to use the Escape key to change modes. Preferably, I'd like to swap the Capslock and Escape keys, but as far as I've heard, that's not possible within Vim itself. Most "solutions" I've found involve changing the key on a global level (using `xmodmap` or whatever), but I don't really want that. If there's an easy way to swap Capslock and Escape **only in Vim**, please let me know.

Another common thing I've heard of is using "Ctrl-[" as an equivalent to Escape. However, because I'm using a German keyboard with a different layout, that's not an option. So, I thought I'd use `noremap <C-ü> <Esc>` in Vim (the "ü" key on a German keyboard is in the same place as the "[" key on US keyboards), but that didn't work, either. I'm assuming that's because "ü" isn't an ASCII character. Is there any way to get either of these options working?

**UPDATE**: Well, this is strange. After experimenting some more, it seems that "Ctrl-ü" does work after all. I'm not sure what happened – maybe I messed up some encoding-related settings while trying different things? If there is no good solution for remapping capslock, I guess I will stick with "Ctrl-ü".

Comment: Not an 'easy' solution you are looking for, but you could go through the source, change the bindings and recompile vim.

Comment: Well, I could, but honestly, that's the last thing I'd do - I wouldn't even be able to update Vim without changing the source every time! Globally remapping Capslock doesn't seem nearly as bad ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yeah, eventually I decided to go with `<C-ü>` because it doesn't conflict with anything else and because it's the same as `<C-[>` on US keyboards.

However, because I'm getting tired of using the German keyboard layout for programming (for example, to get "{" you need to type "Alt Gr-7"), I'm switching my keyboard to US-International, which essentially has a similar effect as far as Vim is concerned. It also helps if you want to want to get into the habit of touch-typing; you actually can't look at the keyboard because the keys aren't labeled "correctly" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people use `jk`:

```
inoremap jk <Esc>
```

You can also simply do `<C-c>`.

Comment: I really don't like the idea of remapping normal character sequences to Escape (what if I want to type "jk"?), so that won't work for me. `<C-c>` is _not_ the same as Escape, so no luck there, either...

Comment: It's very very close. Compare `:help i_<esc>` and `:help i_ctrl-c`.

Comment: i see more often jj suggested than jk, but anything you don't type often will do, to type jj or jk if it's mapped to esc, just type the first character, wait for about half a second, and then type the second one, it won't call the mapping, it's a slowdown, but if you don't type jj or jk often, it's not a big problem.

Comment: yep I'v got inoremap jj set also, I don't know of any word that has 2 j's in succession, and in the unlikely case that you want to use the sequence anyway just waiting a bit between the two j keypresses would work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative that may be useful to you! It involves changing the keyboard file related to VIM. I found this suggestion [on this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HskQMorxboY)

```
$ cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
sudo vim pc
```

to edit the capslock key to escape, change the capslock line to read as follows:

```
key <CAPS> { [ Escape ] };
```

`:wq` # to write and close the file

Log out and log back into the machine and it should be updated!