# Key binding in Vim - <C-ç> doesn't work

Tags: vim

I cannot bind the  key stroke and I don't know why. Can someone explain why this happens or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your terminal emulator probably can't handle it. Does it work in gvim?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work in GVim too.

Comment: That is a similar question indeed, however, the solution is not what I want, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Links: similar question for `noremap <C-ü> <Esc>` at http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096039 and for `<C-ĝ>` at http://stackoverflow.com/q/16013290.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.)

In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Comment: Typing <C-ç> in insert or command-line mode, is the same as typing only 'ç'

Comment: Well, then you unfortunately can only map `ç`, not in combination with Ctrl.